# PHP Echo shows full JSON line data not only what i required

Tags: php, json

recently i used some JSON data in JQuery. now i want the same thing in PHP.
For Example:

MySQL query returns data like

```
$result='{"username":"john","age":"18", "birthdate":"19880221"}';
```

but when i echo this data in PHP, like:

```
echo $result.username;
echo $result.age;
```

it shows output:

```
{"username":"john","age":"18", "birthdate":"19880221"}.username
{"username":"john","age":"18", "birthdate":"19880221"}.age
```

but i want output this:

```
John
18
```

Comment: Can you include the PHP line that retrieves the data from MySql ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is not Javascript, the `.` operator is for string concatenation and PHP has no native support for JSON syntax. You need to convert the JSON formatted data into an array and use array syntax:

```
$result = json_decode($result, true);
echo $result['username'];
echo $result['age'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result is actually just a string, formated like JSON. It's not an array in PHP. If U want to handle JSON output, you can use json_decode() first, and then get access to data via PHP array syntax like this:

```
$result = json_decode($result,true);
echo $result['some_key'];
```

Answer (score 0):

php is not js. you have to decode data first, using json_decode

if $result *really* contains the data you posted